# Implementation of QAbstractItemModel for hierarchical data

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I have hierarchical data structure (items in 3d space) and I need to display this data in TreeView. As I understand to implement this in Qt I need to implement QAbstractItemModel by my  data and I'm having troubles with it for some reasons:

1. my data has a lot of modifications methods, so i need to put a lot
   of notification code (it bloats my model)
2. my data undergoes a lot of changes, it might be a bottleneck to
   notify each update with calls to AboutToSmthChange. and SmthChanged

I'm thinking about two possible solutions:

1. Implement QAbstractItemModel just like proxy model that stores copy
   of hierarchical data with links to actual nodes and update this
   proxy model by comparison with source model on demand (using
   Qt::Queued Connection to connect update signal with slot).
2. Simply use QTreewidget and update it on demand.

And my question is what is the best way to handle this situation if my application have a workflow like: it has multiple updates of data and data structure that takes usually 10-500ms, and all data contains no more than 10000 nodes, data changes in turn updates tree view and after several seconds everything repeats

BTW: From TreeView point of view my data structure is read only, all changes is performed on my data and then simply reflecting in TreeView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Qt model can certainly act as a proxy. The update notifications are only a bottleneck if you measure them to be a bottleneck. Using queued connections currently adds `2+n` heap allocations per call, where `n` is the number of arguments, so using them is counterproductive in your case.

Ultimately, Qt needs a subscription-based change notifications as a tree view may not be interested in updates to invisible items. But then, such notifications have only a nominal overhead as the view doesn't do anything heavy with them.

Comment: I want to send only one queued signal for model update (if the signal has been already sent and model hasn't been updated yet there is no reason to send it again), compare whole model and update changed nodes only since my model is rather small and it shouldn't take more than a fraction of second to update the model in the worst case. Anyway it would be better to update visible nodes only, but as far as I understand it's impossible without reinventing the wheel with Qt by writing my own View widgets.

Comment: @Rem If you want to indicate a model reset then, well, indicate a model reset :) You don't need to do anything fancy at all then. The queuing of the signal is pointless, since there's no way for you to check whether the signal was received yet or not (it can be connected to multiple recipients, etc.). So far it looks to me like you're doing premature optimization.

Comment: Ultimately I want to found something like this: [link](http://www.delphi-gems.com/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview)

Comment: @Rem I think you're worrying about things that ultimately don't matter. You'd need to have measurements that show that those things do matter first. Qt is rough around the edges here, but you really can't try to devise workarounds around a problem that you haven't shown to exist yet.

Comment: To Kuba ober: since my app is single threaded and i'm going to have only one recipient and a single place for model comparison and update (model has a single point from which it sends updates to all views) it will be easy for me just to use boolean variable. As for me I most afraid not of premature optimizations, but of over-engineering))

Comment: To Kuba ober: Yeah, I want something like modelReset() but I want to preserve expanded nodes and TreeView scrolling positions. So modelReset is not a way to go for me.